# Finding average temperature from a CSV file using CSVParser

Tags: java, csv, if-statement

I have tested the code and it works as per required. However, I would want to be abe to print System.out.println("No temperatures with that humidity") if the currRow is >= value passed when calling averageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile() from the testaverageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile(). How do I do this?

```
         public double averageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile(CSVParser parser, int value){
         double averageTemperatureWithHighHumidity =0.0;
         int numberOfDays = 0;
         double sum =0;
         double averageTemp = 0;

`             for (CSVRecord currentRow : parser){

            double currRow = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("Humidity"));
              if (currRow >= value){


                  double temp = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("TemperatureF"));

                   sum +=temp;
                   numberOfDays++;

                } 
                averageTemp = sum/numberOfDays;            
            }
    return averageTemp;

    } 




    public void testAverageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile(){
            FileResource fr = new FileResource();      
            double testAverageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile = averageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile(fr.getCSVParser(),80);
           System.out.println("Average temperature when high humidity is " +  testAverageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile );

    }
```

Comment: So you want to add some code. What hinders you to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
public double averageTemperatureWithHighHumidityInFile(CSVParser parser, int value){
     double averageTemperatureWithHighHumidity =0.0;
     int numberOfDays = 0;
     double sum =0;
     double averageTemp = 0;
     for (CSVRecord currentRow : parser){

        double currRow = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("Humidity"));
          if (currRow >= value){


              double temp = Double.parseDouble(currentRow.get("TemperatureF"));

               sum +=temp;
               numberOfDays++;

            } else{

            System.out.println("Average temperature with that humidity does not exisi");
            }
                averageTemp = sum/numberOfDays;   
        } 
return averageTemp;

}
```